# Show that linear operator is symmetric with respect to scalar product

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

For $a,c\in\mathbb{R}$, consider 
$$
u_t=u_{xx}+cu_x+au
$$
on $(-L,L)$ with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions and with solutions in $L^2([-L,L])$.

If we make the Ansatz $v=e^{\alpha x}u$ and choose $\alpha=c/2$, we get the transformed equation
$$
v_t=v_{xx}+(a-\alpha^2)v.
$$

Now, I have to show that the linear operator $\mathcal{L}$ of this transformed equation is symmetric with respect to the canonical scalar product. I am not completely sure if I understood what has to be done.

---

But I think the operator is $\mathcal{L}=\partial_{xx}+ a-\alpha^2$ and it is to show that 
$$
\langle\mathcal{L}u,w\rangle_{L^2}=\int_{-L}^Lwu_{xx}\, dx+(a-\alpha^2)\int_{-L}^Luw\, dx
$$
and
$$
\langle u,\mathcal{L}w\rangle_{L^2}=\int_{-L}^Luw_{xx}\, dx+(a-\alpha^2)\int_{-L}^L uw\, dx
$$
are identical.

I think it remains to show that
$$
\int_{-L}^Lwu_{xx}\, dx = \int_{-L}^Luw_{xx}\, dx
$$

By partial Integration, we have
$$
\int_{-L}^Lwu_{xx}\, dx =\underbrace{\left. wu_x\right|_{-L}^L}_{w(L)u_x(L)-w(-L)u_x(-L)=0}-\int_{-L}^Lw_xu_x\, dx=-\int_{-L}^Lw_xu_x\, dx
$$

and similarly
$$
\int_{-L}^Luw_{xx}\, dx =-\int_{-L}^Lw_xu_x\, dx
$$

That already should be the proof, shouldn't it?

Comment: I think the linear operator in this case corresponds to $\mathcal{L} = \partial_t - \partial_{xx} - (a-\alpha^2)$. You already figured out how to deal with $\partial_{xx} + (a-\alpha^2)$, so you really just need to show that $\langle\partial_t u,w\rangle = \langle u,\partial_t w\rangle$ for any $u,w$ in the domain of $\mathcal{L}$.

Comment: By the way: Isn't this property called 'self adjoined' instead of symmetric?

Comment: They are different! To show that $\mathcal{L}$ is self-adjoint, you need to show that $\mathcal{L}$ is symmetric and the domain of the adjoint of $\mathcal{L}$ is contained in the domain of $\mathcal{L}$.